# Error: Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart

[screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XxJo.jpg)

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:5405:11)
at Object.castError (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:5362:15)
at Object.cast [as as] (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:5686:17)
at dart.LegacyType.new.as (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:7363:60)
at new module_model.ModuleModel.fromJson (http://localhost:50026/packages/sixam_mart/data/model/response/module_model.dart.lib.js:161:29)
at new config_model.ConfigModel.fromJson (http://localhost:50026/packages/sixam_mart/data/model/response/config_model.dart.lib.js:614:51)
at splash_controller.SplashController.new.getConfigData (http://localhost:50026/packages/sixam_mart/data/repository/auth_repo.dart.lib.js:51322:35)
at getConfigData.next (<anonymous>)
at http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:43063:33
at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:42919:58)
at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:37493:29)
at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:38088:49)
at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:38126:17)
at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:37955:23)
at http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:38193:40
at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:42919:58)
at _FutureListener.then.handleValue (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:37493:29)
at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:38088:49)
at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:38126:17)
at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:37955:23)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:37991:35)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:43223:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:43229:13)
at http://localhost:50026/dart_sdk.js:38359:9
```

I've been dealing with this problem for days, I wasn't getting such a problem before, I changed computers, zero files and the same problem, how can I solve it I'm new to flutter

It builds but does not open the application and at the same time, when I open debug, I get the same error. The application does not open.

```
class ModuleModel {
  int id;
  String moduleName;
  String moduleType;
  String thumbnail;
  String icon;
  int themeId;
  String description;
  int storesCount;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;

  ModuleModel(
      {this.id,
        this.moduleName,
        this.moduleType,
        this.thumbnail,
        this.storesCount,
        this.icon,
        this.themeId,
        this.description,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt,
      });

  ModuleModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    moduleName = json['module_name'];
    moduleType = json['module_type'];
    thumbnail = json['thumbnail'];
    icon = json['icon'];
    themeId = json['theme_id'];
    description = json['description'];
    storesCount = json['stores_count'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['module_name'] = this.moduleName;
    data['module_type'] = this.moduleType;
    data['thumbnail'] = this.thumbnail;
    data['icon'] = this.icon;
    data['theme_id'] = this.themeId;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['stores_count'] = this.storesCount;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a bug in `ModuleModel.fromJson()` but don't show your code or an example of the JSON it's meant to consume.

Comment: how do i do this

Comment: You edit the question and paste in the relevant bit from `module_model.dart`. Edit the `fromJson` method or named constructor and print its input parameter - update the question with the result. Or print out the whole of the JSON before you decode it.

Comment: I shared the code with you above can you help me fix it?